# SAP Webservice problems

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, abap, sap-basis

I need to make a SAP webservice out of a function module.

I think I tried every possible way to do so but I can't figure it out how to get it running.

I always get the same error when testing with SOAPUI:

> Service cannot be reached.

Anyone here that could help me solving my issue?

Thanks!

I tried all possible Binding-Configurations and always got the same error. I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Comment: check this https://medium.com/codex/soap-webservice-from-abap-fm-d53bc43b5b8d

Answer (score 1):

SAP Netweaver publishing WSDL under different endpoint then real endpoint. So you need to ensure that you are using endpoint in the WSDL.

The next step is checking this endpoint reachable from outside SAP server network. Generally companies using web dispatcher, proxy server or other stuff to protect their SAP server. So given endpoint don't work in the WSDL file. You need to get working endpoint from basis team.

Also compere other working custom services from the Soamanager.